# What does 'do a 180' mean in Halo 3?

Tags: halo-3

I was reading this tip on my Halo 3 guide. It said to find a certain skull on the Covenant. I had to climb up this pathway at the 2 tower, turn left, then do a "180". How am I suppose to do a 180?

Comment: 180 means turn 180 degrees.  ie. Go back the way you just came.

Answer (score 6):

"Do a 180" means to turn around.  Specifically, turn 180 degrees, which is a half-circle.  A 360 is therefore turning completely around to face the same way as you started.

This is not Halo-specific, it's a [common English term](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/180) which is frequently used in so-called "[extreme sports](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0jRtz24kZ4)."